# How to check if the key the i want is existing in python

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple of objects that looks like this:

```
('MATE555', ([('Wdfd',7), ('dfs', 2), ('Tdfs77', 2), ('Fsf1', 1), ('s01', 1), ('Bdf1', 1), ('fs01', 1)],))
```

and i want function created which would check if the name key exist.if it exist it would return the 2nd part of the tuple, if not it would return 'no key'.
example

> get_list('MATE555') would return
>   [('Wdfd',7), ('dfs', 2), ('Tdfs77',
>   2), ('Fsf1', 1), ('s01', 1), ('Bdf1',
>   1), ('fs01', 1)] 
>  and
>   get_list("HIW6') would return 'no key'

Comment: Should we do your homework? Accessing a tuple item using the some_tuple[index] is very basic Python. Please read the Python tutorial.

Comment: my homework is huge and i already did some of it however some i still dont understand like this problem here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if your_list[0] == 'MATE555':
   print your_list[1]
else:
   print 'no key'
```

Please read the Python tutorial first...this is really Python basics...

Comment: oh what if you have a lot of keys not only this. will it be.. something like list[key] and check if the key exist?

Comment: moving this code into a function with related function parameters is straight-forward.

Comment: so lets say.. def get_list(name): if your_list[0] == name, print.. blah blah,, else: print 'no key'?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using tuple object for 'key -> value' data model ?
Python has a HashMap class called "Dictionary" which should be used instead of tuple for 'key -> value' data model as it offers more flexibility than tuple:

Creating dict from list:

```
your_dict = dict([(key1, value1), (key2, value2), (key3, value3), ...])
```

So in you case:

```
your_dict = dict([your_tuple])
```

Searching for key in dict:

```
if your_key in your_dict:
    print your_dict[your_key]
else:
    print "Key not present."
```

Adding new 'key -> value' pair:

```
your_dict[new_key] = new_value_object
```

Deleting 'key -> value' pair from dict:

```
del your_dict[key]
```

etc... More can be found here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Comment: Your are welcome. You may like to browse http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ to familiarize yourself.